# Where is the error in this stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROC InserimentoValori()
BEGIN
  DECLARE @caratteri varchar(30);
  set @caratteri = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE x <=100 DO
  INSERT INTO Persona(nome,cognome,eta) VALUES((SELECT @caratteri = substring(@caratteri +1),(SELECT @caratteri = sebstring(@caratteri +1),(SELECT floor(rand() * 99) AS randNum));
  SET x = x+1;
END WHILE
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to create a stored procedure that insert random values into the table.
Thanks

Comment: In what way does your code not work?  Or did you just want us to randomly guess?

Comment: Sebstring is a clerical error...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors.

We don't "declare" *user defined variables* in MySQL. Just `SET` them.

If you want to `DECLARE` a variable within a procedure, that needs to be a *procedure variable*.

A *user defined variable* has a name that starts with the **`@`** character. A *procedure* variable cannot start with a **`@`** character.

So, a line like this is an error:

```
DECLARE @foo ...
```

If you want to use a user defined variable, remove that line. If you want to use a procedure variable, remove the `@` from the beginning of the variable name (and make that same change everywhere you want to reference the procedure variable `foo`.)

And `SEBSTRING` is not the name of a MySQL provided function.

Also, a boolean expression in a SELECT list of a query will return 0, 1 or NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT @caratteri = substring(@caratteri +1)
```

That expression is comparing the value on the left side of the `=` with the value on the right, and is going to return `1` if they are equal, or `0` if the aren't, or NULL if either of the values is NULL.

To perform an assignment to a user defined variable in a SELECT statement, use the Pascal-style **`:=`** operator.

(If you meant to do an assignment, the design makes it look like you are gogin to lop off the first character each time through the loop; that's eventually going to be an empty string, if we loop enough times. You may want to think about leaving the string static. Consider incrementing integer values, and use those as arguments in SUBSTRING function. And you can use the `MOD` operator to get the integer value to "wrap".)

Comment: FYI: StackOverflow is designed as a **question** and **answer** site. It's not designed for dumping "pleez debug my codez for me" disguised as a question. For further information, please see [ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)